# Apps Script: How to load dialog boxes in a loop at the click of two buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Basically, I am comparing the data in two sheets, so I want to show a dialog box with the data of two cells from two sheets and two buttons for the user to select which data cell is correct. Then I would like to loop through all the data that differed from one sheet to the other.

How can I show a dialog with the data, make the script wait for the button to be pressed and then go to the next item on the list?

This is the script that I have so far:

```js
<script>
  function myfunction() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(qcComparison).qcGetData();
  }

  function qcComparison(sheetsData) {
    var sheet1 = sheetsData["sheet1"];
    var sheet2 = sheetsData["sheet2"];
    var lastRow = sheet1.length;
    var lastCol = sheet1[0].length

    var headers = sheet1[0];

    for (var row=1; row<=lastRow; row++) {
      for (var col=0; col<lastCol; col++) {
      // Do the comparison one cell at a time
        var value1 = sheet1[row][col];
        var value2 = sheet1[row][col];

        if (value1 != value2) {
          // Do something
        }
      }
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myfunction());
</script>
```

And this is the HTML dialog that I wan to update with the data:

```html
     <table id="qc-table" class="qc-table">
        <tr>
          <td><button id="sheet-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Sheet 1</button></td>
          <td class="profile-data"><p id="sheet-1-profile">Data from cell 1</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="sheet-2" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Sheet 2</button></td>
          <td class="profile-data"><p id="sheet-2-profile">Data form cell 2</p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a dialog box when the values are not equal you can call an HTML service to create the HTML within Apps Script and then use `getUi().showModalDialog`.

EDIT: `for` loops aren't the best solution since they will continue to execute while the dialog box is open. It is better to use recursion in this case.

Sample code below:

```
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var range1 = sheet1.getRange(1,1,sheet1.getLastRow(),sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var range2 = sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn()).getValues();

function qcComparison() {
    var row = 0, col = 0;
    compare(row, col);
}

function compare(row, col) {
    Logger.log(row, col);
    if (range1[row][col] != range2[row][col]) {
          Logger.log("Different values!");
          var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
          html.row = row;
          html.col = col;
          html.cell1 = range1[row][col];
          html.cell2 = range2[row][col];
          var htmlOutput = html.evaluate();
          SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Choice');
    }
    else {
          compareNext(row, col);
    }
}

function compareNext(row, col) {
    Logger.log("Compare next", row, col);
    if (col < range1[row].length) {
      if (row < range1[col].length-1) {
            compare(++row, col);
      }
      else {
            row = 0;
            compare(row, ++col);
      }
    }
    return;
}
```

The HTML is changed to accept values from Apps Script, sample code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
         <table id="qc-table" class="qc-table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="sheet-1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="google.script.run.setSheet1(<?=row?>,<?=col?>,<?=cell1?>);google.script.host.close();">Sheet 1</button></td>
          <td class="profile-data"><p id="sheet-1-profile">Data from Sheet 1: <?=cell1?>   </p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="sheet-2" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="google.script.run.setSheet2(<?=row?>,<?=col?>,<?=cell2?>);google.script.host.close();">Sheet 2</button></td>
          <td class="profile-data"><p id="sheet-2-profile">Data from Sheet 2: <?=cell2?>   </p></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that the script now runs functions upon click of Sheet 1 or Sheet 2 to update the values:

```
function setSheet1(row, col, value) {
    sheet2.getRange(++row,++col).setValue(value);
    compareNext(--row, --col);
}

function setSheet2(row, col, value) {
    sheet1.getRange(++row,++col).setValue(value);
    compareNext(--row, --col);
}
```

References:

[showModalDialog()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)

[Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

[Communication between HTML and Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Loading the data into the dialog is not the problem (although using these scriptlets is a good alternative that I was not aware of). My doubt is how to have the script "wait" for either one of the buttons to be clicked to move to the next iteration on the loop to display the next data values.

Comment: @everspader Found a solution for the script to wait for input from the dialog box :) Edited answer.

Comment: that was a good solution. I just needed to tweak a few things like the indices but it works just fine. I am wondering if maybe I could put this script inside the HTML and keep changing the text of the elements instead of loading the page every time to make it faster.