# Create a Dialog box with custom buttons and Links

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have an internal emailing list that I want to subscribe new employees to and unsubscribe employees that have left.
I'm using a google sheet with a check box to do this. Mainly because this sheet is already used in the HR process, so it's easy to remember to do.

When the check the box is checked I want a dialog box to pop up with a buttons that says
Subscribe and Unsubscribe. These buttons are linked to locations within the emailing tool that allows people to subscribe or unsunscribe.

The scribe I have at the moment is

```
    var result = ui.alert
  (
     'What would you like to do?',
     'Subscribe a new Employee or' + "\n" + 'Unsubcribe an employee thats left',
      ui.ButtonSet.Subscribe_Unsubscribe
  );

  if (result == ui.Button.Subscribe) 
  {
    
  }else
  {
     ui.alert('Employee has been removed from the internal mailing list');
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how if by changing the button set names work this way and I dont know how to assign a link to the buttons either.

Looking forward to your responses!!!

Comment: It's quite easy to create a dialog with SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModal or showModeless and then add the Html as text directly into dialog if there are only a couple of buttons.  You can create a form and submit it directly to the server with google.script.run.  You can also create it as a sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1:

First you would need to create an installable trigger that would execute a function in GAS whenever a cell is edited.

You can find an explanation / reference on Installable Triggers here:

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Why installable triggers? Because you would need to connect to an email service, which requires authorization.

**Sample Code:**

```
/**
 * Creates a trigger for when a spreadsheet is edited.
 */
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

### Step 2:

To create custom dialog boxes you need to create the HTML file from scratch in GAS, the IDE allows you to create HTML files from the menu.

Then in your script you would need to use `getUi().showModalDialog` to display the dialog box.

I have some sample code in a Stack Overflow post here: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65223874/apps-script-how-to-load-dialog-boxes-in-a-loop-at-the-click-of-two-buttons/65225749#65225749)

Note that the HTML would need both `onclick="google.script.run"` and `onclick="google.script.host.close()"` parameters to execute functions within Apps Script.

### References:

[showModalDialog()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title)

[Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

[Communication between HTML and Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)