# Pull data to a html page from Google Sheets based on user input

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google spreadsheet with several rows of data in four columns whose headings are

Employee ID |
Name |
Age |
Designation |

I want to create a web App (html page with form elements) in which if I put in the Employee ID value (which is unique) in a text field and click Submit, the other three details (viz. Name, Age, Designation) of only that particular Employee are displayed in a table below in that same page.

I was not able to see any examples where select parts of the sheet are returned as a table based on user input value.

Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

While I will not be able to code your web app, you can start by researching [client-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#index.html_1) in HTML. The `google.script.run` API is the most basic call, you can start on that.

You may want to research on scriptlets as well. Basically this allows you to execute Apps Script code in your HTML using the tags `<?` and  `?>`.

The [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#standard_scriptlets) documentation provides some examples that you can expand to suit your need.

You may also want to study some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65223874/apps-script-how-to-load-dialog-boxes-in-a-loop-at-the-click-of-two-buttons/65225749#65225749).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Note I haven't tested this so some tweaking may be required.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="msg"></div><!-- You can add css to hide these and then turn them on with js as required -->
    <div id="found"></div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Enter Employee ID" /><br />
      <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="processForm(this.parentNode);" />
    </form>
    <script>
      function processForm(obj) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler((obj)=>{
          if(!obj.msg) {
            document.getElementById('found').innerHTML=`EmployeeId: ${obj.id} Name: ${obj.n} Age: ${obj.a} Designation: ${obj.d}`;
          }else{
            document.getElementById('found').innerHTML=`Message: ${obj.msg}`;
          }
        })
        .search(obj);
      }
      console.log("My Code");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

GS:

```
function mysearch(obj) {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [hA, ...data]=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx={};
  let found=false;
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{idx[h]=i;});
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    if(data[i][idx['EmployeeID']]==obj.id) {
      Logger.log({id:obj.id,n:data[i][idx['Name']],a:data[i][idx['Age']],d:data[i][idx['Designation']]});
      found=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(found){
    return {id:obj.id,n:data[i][idx['Name']],a:data[i][idx['Age']],d:data[i][idx['Designation']]};
  } else {
    return {msg:"Not found"}
  }
}

function launchMyNewDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah1'),'test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne for the quick response. I am new to this. When I deploy as a webApp i see the page with a search box, but when i enter a value and click on the search button, nothing happens. Am i supposed to add something in the line below in place of the three dots. Sorry if this is a stupid question. const [hA, ...data]=sh.getDataRange().getValues(); ?

Comment: I guess I'll have to test it hold on for few minutes

Comment: Thank you so much. Very grateful to you. In the line if(r[idx['EmployeeID']==obj.id]), should it be if(r[idx['EmployeeID']==obj])  instead of obj.id?

Comment: have you added the sheet name

Comment: in regard the idx properties they should match whatever the headers are and I uually remove any spaces in the properties or the headers

Comment: Thanks for your  assistance I can see that you know something about what you're doing

Comment: Yes i added the sheet name. Also my column names in the sheet as exactly as in your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228803/discussion-between-cooper-and-user1327454).